# How can I add placeholder text when the editor is empty

Tags: ace-editor

How can I add placeholder text when the editor is empty?

It should go away as soon as typing starts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a listener for the `input` event and add a div with text when needed like this:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor", {
  theme: "ace/theme/chaos"
})

function update() {
    var shouldShow = !editor.session.getValue().length;
    var node = editor.renderer.emptyMessageNode;
    if (!shouldShow && node) {
        editor.renderer.scroller.removeChild(editor.renderer.emptyMessageNode);
        editor.renderer.emptyMessageNode = null;
    } else if (shouldShow && !node) {
        node = editor.renderer.emptyMessageNode = document.createElement("div");
        node.textContent = "placeholder"
        node.className = "ace_emptyMessage"
        node.style.padding = "0 9px"
        node.style.position = "absolute"
        node.style.zIndex = 9
        node.style.opacity = 0.5
        editor.renderer.scroller.appendChild(node);
    }
}
editor.on("input", update);
setTimeout(update, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script> 
  <style>
    #editor { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="editor"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i add it for angular4 ?

Comment: You could use component life-cycle hooks and add this logic accordingly, no?

Comment: This seems to work well for some, but not all, ace themes. For example, a placeholder is shown when text is removed from the editor at https://vnijs.shinyapps.io/shinyAce-01-basic/ for the "ambience" theme but not for the "chaos" theme. Any suggestions?

Comment: placeholder was getting behind the line highlight, updated the example to  handle that case

Comment: There is now a 'placeholder' option

Answer (score 4):

You can use `placeholder: "Your Placeholder Text"` option to put placeholder in your Ace Editor.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({
  mode: "ace/mode/css",
  theme: "ace/theme/cobalt",
  placeholder: "Enter CSS Code",
})
```

```css
#editor { 
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/mode-css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/theme-cobalt.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="editor"></div>
```